# me coge bien la letra al visualizarlo en chrome a través de dreamweaver pero en mi servidor no me las coge

Tags: css, dreamweaver

tengo una web alojada en mi servidor, pero no me coge los estilos de letra css, el caso es que en el dreamweaver al ver la web en Chrome si me lo coge bien con la letra pero en el servidor me pone la letra que hay por defecto en cada sistema, vamos una muy fea.

https://www.linceiberico.es/WEB_ACTIVE/html/index.html

Gracias

Comment: La página no carga o va extremadamente lenta a la hora de cargar. No he podido verla

Comment: https://fonts.google.com/share?selection.family=Source%20Sans%20Pro:wght@200
si no la ves al subir el html es por que la tenes instalada localmente

Comment: Gracias, seguramente sea eso en el codigo tengo esto <script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro.js"></script>
como puedo ponerlo bien, a ver si hay suerte, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu local es http

pero tu server es https

los navegadores bloquean el acceso a recursos http cuando la pagina esta siendo revisada por https.

solo llama a tus recursos con https y se cargaran OK.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La mejor practica es que todos los recursos sean cargados por tu propio server.

Comment: Hola John efectivamente !!!, te lo agradezco muchísimo, una web cambia mucho por una tipografía, erres un crack !! Voy a ver como te doy puntos , muchísimas gracias !!!, como siempre en html una simple letra cambia el código, te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: No se como darte una buena puntuación, bueno una excelente puntuación.

Comment: jejeje la información es par ayudar al prójimo, no por una puntuación 

Comment: Pues muchas gracias otra vez John, tengo otro problema en otra web, no se si comentártelo por aquí o en otra pregunta. Bueno te lo comento por aquí tengo unas imágenes en una web que hice con algo de javascript creo, es de hace muchos años, y no encuentro como cambiar los links de esas imágenes, me va a la web de la marca, en vez de a mi servidor. Te paso el link, si es muy enrevesado no te preocupes, gracias John. te paso el link, sería por ejemplo en las 4 imagenes que salen de robots.          https://www.linceiberico.es/html/index.html

Comment: Hola John, no te preocupes ya lo tengo. Gracias por tu otra solución